Proguard and GSON combination causing issues
I have been using GSON with proguard enabled in my app. I am saving an object in shared prefs using GSON like this
DriverBalanceStat class
public class DriverBalanceStat {
public Double Balance;
public Integer PendingDays;
public boolean IsMeterBlocked;
public Long BalanceDate;
public double CashbackAmount;
public Boolean IsAllowCashTrip;
public Boolean IsAllowCashlessTrip;

public DriverBalanceStat(Double balance, Integer pendingDays, boolean isMeterBlocked, Long balanceDate,
                         Double cashbackAmount, Boolean isAllowCashTrip, Boolean isAllowCashlessTrip) {
    this.Balance = balance;
    this.PendingDays = pendingDays;
    this.IsMeterBlocked = isMeterBlocked;
    this.BalanceDate = balanceDate;
    this.CashbackAmount = cashbackAmount;
    this.IsAllowCashTrip = isAllowCashTrip;
    this.IsAllowCashlessTrip = isAllowCashlessTrip;
}

}
Setting object in shared pref
    public boolean SetAppPrefsByKey(int key, Object value) {
    synchronized (this) {
        try {
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String json = gson.toJson(value);
            prefsEdit.putString(context.getString(key), json);
            prefsEdit.apply();
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(e);
            return false;
        }
    }
}

Getting object from shared pref
 public Object GetAppObjectByKey(int key, Class<?> cls) {
    synchronized (this) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = prefs.getString(context.getString(key), "");
        return gson.fromJson(json, cls);
    }
}

Whenever i trying to get the values from shared pref using
(DriverBalanceStat) sharedPrefUtil.GetAppObjectByKey(R.string.driver_bal_key, DriverBalanceStat.class)
it throws me fatal error
java.lang.IllegalStateException - Expected an int but was BOOLEAN at line 1 column 24 path $.b 
When i logged the values saved in pref i got the following results
without proguard
{"Balance":-35617.2,"BalanceDate":1717503937502,"CashbackAmount":0.0,"IsAllowCashTrip":true,"IsAllowCashlessTrip":true,"IsMeterBlocked":false,"PendingDays":0}

with proguard
{"a":-0.0,"b":false,"c":1717804886626,"d":true,"e":true}

Problem starts only after i upgrade my gradle plugin to 7.4.2 from 4.x.x
I have added following rule in proguard as well
-keep class com.yego.AppModal.DriverBalanceStat

kindly suggest. My app is breaking in release version

Do it like this.
-keep class com.yego.AppModal.DriverBalanceStat { *; }
